Manual training loops in keras
I have been working on a reinforcement learning project with keras. For that, I have made a keras model which calculates the losses internally, I have implemented a custom Environment layer to it that is analogous of the agent performing the action and the environment outputting the reward and the next state. I am facing the problem on this code snippet
agent.compile(optimizer = "Adam", loss = None)

episodes = 100

input_meaning_space = np.zeros((1, 256))

for m in range(episodes):

    agent.fit(x = input_meaning_space, y = None, epochs = 1)
    output_env = agent.predict(input_meaning_space)

    input_meaning_space = output_env

Where I am facing the following error
{
    "name": "InaccessibleTensorError",
    "message": "<tf.Tensor 'functional_2_1/environment_18_1/Add:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float64> is out of scope and cannot be used here. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.
Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values for more information.

<tf.Tensor 'functional_2_1/environment_18_1/Add:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float64> was defined here:
    File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 88, in _run_code
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel_launcher.py\", line 17, in <module>
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\traitlets\\config\\application.py\", line 1075, in launch_instance
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelapp.py\", line 739, in start
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\tornado\\platform\\asyncio.py\", line 205, in start
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py\", line 638, in run_forever
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py\", line 1971, in _run_once
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\asyncio\\events.py\", line 84, in _run
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 542, in dispatch_queue
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 531, in process_one
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 437, in dispatch_shell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\ipkernel.py\", line 359, in execute_request
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 775, in execute_request
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\ipkernel.py\", line 446, in do_execute
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\zmqshell.py\", line 549, in run_cell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3051, in run_cell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3106, in _run_cell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\async_helpers.py\", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3311, in run_cell_async
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3493, in run_ast_nodes
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3553, in run_code
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_16560\\429774455.py\", line 9, in <module>
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 314, in fit
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 117, in one_step_on_iterator
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 104, in one_step_on_data
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 51, in train_step
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\layers\\layer.py\", line 848, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\ops\\operation.py\", line 48, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 156, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\models\\functional.py\", line 175, in call
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\ops\\function.py\", line 171, in _run_through_graph
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\models\\functional.py\", line 556, in call
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\layers\\layer.py\", line 848, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\ops\\operation.py\", line 48, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 156, in error_handler
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_16560\\2490516789.py\", line 33, in call
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_16560\\2490516789.py\", line 27, in step

The tensor <tf.Tensor 'functional_2_1/environment_18_1/Add:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float64> cannot be accessed from FuncGraph(name=one_step_on_iterator, id=2418230291648), because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=one_step_on_data, id=2418230192832), which is out of scope.",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InaccessibleTensorError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[55], line 9
      5 input_meaning_space = tf.zeros((1, 256))
      7 for m in range(episodes):
----> 9     agent.fit(x = input_meaning_space, y = None, epochs = 1)
     10     output_env = agent.predict(input_meaning_space)
     12     input_meaning_space = output_env

File c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\core\\function\\capture\\capture_container.py:144, in FunctionCaptures.capture_by_value(self, graph, tensor, name)
    141   return self._create_placeholder_helper(graph, tensor, name)
    143 if tensor.graph is not graph:
--> 144   graph._validate_in_scope(tensor)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    145   if name is None:
    146     assert tensor.op is not None, (
    147         tensor.__class__,
    148         dir(tensor),
    149         tensor.__class__.__name__,
    150     )

InaccessibleTensorError: <tf.Tensor 'functional_2_1/environment_18_1/Add:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float64> is out of scope and cannot be used here. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.
Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values for more information.

<tf.Tensor 'functional_2_1/environment_18_1/Add:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float64> was defined here:
    File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 88, in _run_code
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel_launcher.py\", line 17, in <module>
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\traitlets\\config\\application.py\", line 1075, in launch_instance
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelapp.py\", line 739, in start
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\tornado\\platform\\asyncio.py\", line 205, in start
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py\", line 638, in run_forever
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py\", line 1971, in _run_once
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\asyncio\\events.py\", line 84, in _run
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 542, in dispatch_queue
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 531, in process_one
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 437, in dispatch_shell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\ipkernel.py\", line 359, in execute_request
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\kernelbase.py\", line 775, in execute_request
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\ipkernel.py\", line 446, in do_execute
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\zmqshell.py\", line 549, in run_cell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3051, in run_cell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3106, in _run_cell
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\async_helpers.py\", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3311, in run_cell_async
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3493, in run_ast_nodes
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py\", line 3553, in run_code
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_16560\\429774455.py\", line 9, in <module>
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 314, in fit
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 117, in one_step_on_iterator
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 104, in one_step_on_data
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\backend\\tensorflow\\trainer.py\", line 51, in train_step
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\layers\\layer.py\", line 848, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\ops\\operation.py\", line 48, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 156, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\models\\functional.py\", line 175, in call
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\ops\\function.py\", line 171, in _run_through_graph
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\models\\functional.py\", line 556, in call
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\layers\\layer.py\", line 848, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 117, in error_handler
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\ops\\operation.py\", line 48, in __call__
    File \"c:\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 156, in error_handler
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_16560\\2490516789.py\", line 33, in call
    File \"C:\\Users\\win10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_16560\\2490516789.py\", line 27, in step

The tensor <tf.Tensor 'functional_2_1/environment_18_1/Add:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float64> cannot be accessed from FuncGraph(name=one_step_on_iterator, id=2418230291648), because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=one_step_on_data, id=2418230192832), which is out of scope."
}

Which is completely out of my mind, I can't understand this error at all. But I think it is because of the inconsistent training loop, but I am not sure.
I tried using tensorflow operations wherever I can instead of the numpy operations, but the problem won't resolve.
Edits
Here is the agent's keras model
# The custom layer to be used.

class Row_Wise_Softmax(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, temperature=0.00001, **kwargs):

        super(Row_Wise_Softmax, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.temperature = temperature
    
    def call(self, logits):
        """Apply temperature-scaled softmax."""
        scaled_logits = tf.divide(logits, self.temperature)
        return tf.nn.softmax(scaled_logits, axis = -1 )

# The sender part

input_meaning_space = keras.layers.Input(shape = (256, ))
dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(input_meaning_space)
dense_2 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(dense_1)
dense_3 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(dense_2)
dense_4 = keras.layers.Dense(27 * 50, activation = "relu")(dense_3)

reshaped_message = keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape = (27, 50))(dense_4)
message = Row_Wise_Softmax()(reshaped_message)

# The listener part

input_message = message
conv_1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 15, activation = "relu")(input_message)
conv_2 = keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 10, activation = "relu")(conv_1)
flatten = keras.layers.Flatten()(conv_2)
dense_5 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(flatten)
dense_6 = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu")(dense_5)

output_vec = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = "linear")(dense_6)

input_list = [input_meaning_space, output_vec, input_message]

env_output = Environment()(input_list)

agent = keras.Model(input_meaning_space, env_output)
keras.utils.plot_model(agent, show_shapes = True)

Here is the custom Environment layer
class Environment(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(Environment, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.env_meaning_space = tf.zeros(shape = (256, ))

    def step(self, space_bef, space_af, mess): 

        # The environment will take two arrays each representing the meaning space of the agent before, and after.

        space_before = space_bef
        space_after = space_af
        self.message_recieved = mess

        loss = tf.norm(space_before - space_after)

        # The environment will produce a random meaning vector, add it to its meaning space and send it back to the agent.

        transforming_meaning_space = tf.experimental.numpy.random.rand((256))
        self.env_meaning_space = tf.add(self.env_meaning_space, transforming_meaning_space)

        return self.env_meaning_space, loss
    
    def call(self, inputs : list):
        space_before, space_after, message_recieved = inputs
        env_meaning_space, loss = self.step(space_before, space_after, message_recieved)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return env_meaning_space
    
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]


The agent contains an internal "latent space of statements". It is analogous to word embeddings, except it is meant to graph statements. For instance, let's say we have a vector representing "The cat sat on the wall.", when we add the vector "The cat jumped from the wall.", it must represent the vector "There is a cat and a wall." or something similar. The environment will provide the agent with one configuration of the latent space, the agent will perform a transformation on this space, outputting an array of shape (27, 50), which simply represents an array of 50 alphabets, including the space. You can see that in the softmax layer, I have used a very low temperature which will simply cause the results to be one-hot encoded of chracters. This is the sender part, now this message will be sent back to the listener part which will perform a transformation to get a configuration of the statement space, which it will output to the environment. The environment will calculate the loss (It is meant to calculate the reward and punishment, but let it be), and will apply a random vector to the earlier latent space configuration and provide this new latent space to the agent.
You can see that the environment takes one more input, the message generated. I used it for seeing how the model invents the language, which I will implement later.
With training, the agent is expected to invent a new language from the characters given, which could be used for communication with another agent.

Please share the code of your agent model. There's likely an issue in one of your custom layers.
